# AWS CLI S3 command not working with spaces in folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have below command in windows batch script to copy files from local to S3.

```
aws s3 mv D:\Test\test01\test01 s3 and upload test\ s3://bucket/test/test01/
```

When I run the batch file, I am getting below error :-

```
Unknown options: and,upload,test\,s3://bucket/test/test01/
```

Can anyone suggest how I can handle the spaces in the above command for windows batch file.

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting a backslash before the spaces (`test01\s3\and\upload...`), or experiment with putting the complete name in quotes (try single quotes and double quotes).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Tried all the option but its giving same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a \ before the space(s) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a single quote (`'`) works fine.

I did this in a PowerShell window on Windows 2019:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\stack> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\Administrator\stack


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/6/2020   6:35 AM              5 test01 s3 and upload test.txt


PS C:\Users\Administrator\stack> aws s3 cp '.\test01 s3 and upload test.txt' s3://foo
upload: .\test01 s3 and upload test.txt to s3://foo/test01 s3 and upload test.txt

PS C:\Users\Administrator\stack> aws s3 cp 'C:\Users\Administrator\stack\test01 s3 and upload test.txt' s3://foo
upload: .\test01 s3 and upload test.txt to s3://foo/test01 s3 and upload test.txt

PS C:\Users\Administrator\stack> aws s3 mv '.\test01 s3 and upload test.txt' s3://foo
move: .\test01 s3 and upload test.txt to s3://foo/test01 s3 and upload test.txt
```

If you are wanting to **move a folder**, then you will need to add the `--recursive` command:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> aws s3 mv folder1 s3://foo --recursive
move: bar\bar.txt to s3://foo/bar.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a double quote (*"*) before the space(s) worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.